# Cocos2d-x 4.0 new project not includes xcodeproj file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-4.0

I used below command to export from command line.

```
cocos new -l cpp -p com.bfg.mynewpro -d /Volumes/Development/Project/Development/GuruNewPro
```

Exported source not includes main Xcode project file.

How to get it exported ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate the platform specific project files with cmake.

check out the instructions here
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v4/cmake#generate-ios-project

**NOTE:**

cd cocos2d-x

This is actually referring to your game directory. Which in your case i suppose is MyCppGame folder.

Comment: Thanks a lots Darren. Now I successfully run in Cocos2dx iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps for First time Cocos2d-x 4.0 setup in Mac OS**

1. Download Cocos2d-X 4.0+ SDK Here : https://www.cocos2d-x.org/download
2. In Terminal, go inside downloaded cocos2d sdk and execute below command

   ```
   ./setup.py
   ```
3. To create new project from terminal, execute below command.

   ```
   cocos new -l cpp -p com.bfg.newProj -d /Volumes/Development/Project/NewProject
   ```
4. Now generate Xcode.proj file, execute below in terminal

   ```
   cd MyCppGame //your project root folder
   mkdir ios-build && cd ios-build
   cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=iphoneos
   open Cocos2d-x.xcodeproj
   ```

By default cmake not installed in Mac. You can download cmake here https://cmake.org/install/

Install downloaded cmake. Then in terminal execute below command to install command line tool.

```
 PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"

 sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install
```

Other Changes:

1. In Build Settings, Skip install is NO for the main project target
2. Installation Directory under Deployment must be /Applications